# Code gets skip when my program loads

Tags: arrays, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm using Visual Studio and I'm having a problem that I can't seem to find any solution. In the private sub that's associated with the loading of my program, I have to redim two different arrays in order to add a new value to the fifth spot in these two 2d arrays. Sadly, it seems like my program skips the last array code for no reason. For example, this code only redim the tbNoteIniGr2 and skip tbNoteIniGr1:

```
Private Sub frmMain_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.Width = 380


    ReDim Preserve tbNoteIniGr2(tbNoteIniGr2.GetLength(0) - 1, tbNoteIniGr2.GetLength(1))
    For i = 0 To tbNoteIniGr2.GetLength(0)
        inNoteExamens1 = CInt(tbNoteIniGr2(i, 1)) + CInt(tbNoteIniGr2(i, 2)) + CInt(tbNoteIniGr2(i, 4))
        If inNoteExamens1 >= 45 Then
            inNoteFinale1 = inNoteExamens1 + CInt(tbNoteIniGr2(i, 3))
        Else
            inNoteFinale1 = inNoteExamens1 + CInt(CInt(tbNoteIniGr2(i, 3)) * inNoteExamens1 / 75)
        End If
        tbNoteIniGr2(i, 5) = inNoteFinale1
    Next

    ReDim Preserve tbNoteIniGr1(tbNoteIniGr1.GetLength(0) - 1, tbNoteIniGr1.GetLength(1))
    For i = 0 To tbNoteIniGr1.GetLength(0)
        inNoteExamens = CInt(tbNoteIniGr1(i, 1)) + CInt(tbNoteIniGr1(i, 2)) + CInt(tbNoteIniGr1(i, 4))
        If inNoteExamens >= 45 Then
            inNoteFinale = inNoteExamens + CInt(tbNoteIniGr1(i, 3))
        Else
            inNoteFinale = inNoteExamens + CInt(CInt(tbNoteIniGr1(i, 3)) * inNoteExamens / 75)
        End If
        tbNoteIniGr1(i, 5) = inNoteFinale
    Next
End Sub
```

Unlike this code which redim tbNoteIniGr1 and skips tbNoteIniGr2

```
Private Sub frmMain_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
Me.Width = 380

ReDim Preserve tbNoteIniGr1(tbNoteIniGr1.GetLength(0) - 1, tbNoteIniGr1.GetLength(1))
For i = 0 To tbNoteIniGr1.GetLength(0)
    inNoteExamens = CInt(tbNoteIniGr1(i, 1)) + CInt(tbNoteIniGr1(i, 2)) + CInt(tbNoteIniGr1(i, 4))
    If inNoteExamens >= 45 Then
        inNoteFinale = inNoteExamens + CInt(tbNoteIniGr1(i, 3))
    Else
        inNoteFinale = inNoteExamens + CInt(CInt(tbNoteIniGr1(i, 3)) * inNoteExamens / 75)
    End If
    tbNoteIniGr1(i, 5) = inNoteFinale
Next

ReDim Preserve tbNoteIniGr2(tbNoteIniGr2.GetLength(0) - 1, tbNoteIniGr2.GetLength(1))
For i = 0 To tbNoteIniGr2.GetLength(0)
    inNoteExamens1 = CInt(tbNoteIniGr2(i, 1)) + CInt(tbNoteIniGr2(i, 2)) + CInt(tbNoteIniGr2(i, 4))
    If inNoteExamens1 >= 45 Then
        inNoteFinale1 = inNoteExamens1 + CInt(tbNoteIniGr2(i, 3))
    Else
        inNoteFinale1 = inNoteExamens1 + CInt(CInt(tbNoteIniGr2(i, 3)) * inNoteExamens1 / 75)
    End If
    tbNoteIniGr2(i, 5) = inNoteFinale1
Next
```

End Sub
I use the step-by-step debugging and it simply skips the last part so I'm confused. Oh and by the way, these are my variables

```
Dim tbNoteIniGr1(,) As String = {{"Jean Narrace", "16", "8", "13", "10"}, {"Chu Paspire", "20", "20", "23", "24"}, {"Yésuis Parfait", "25", "25", "25", "25"},
                                 {"Moyende Moyenner", "20", "18", "20", "12"}, {"Ia Rienla", "19", "24", "21", "22"}, {"Chue Troisième", "21", "22", "24", "24"},
                                 {"Pépé Lacasse", "21", "21", "21", "11"}, {"Jvatu Couler", "19", "18", "14", "10"}, {"Ungars Sessaye", "0", "0", "0", "25"},
                                 {"Mpassetu Tonlab", "10", "10", "25", "10"}, {"Cava Mieux", "10", "15", "20", "25"}, {"Quéyé Suisbonnw", "24", "24", "24", "24"},
                                 {"Sexy Body", "24", "6", "15", "24"}, {"Yvon Meravoir", "12", "11", "18", "15"}, {"Jeannez Assez", "25", "15", "5", "0"},
                                 {"Téreize Constance", "13", "13", "13", "13"}, {"Déhaut Etdébas", "20", "5", "25", "9"}, {"Jpasse Saligne", "13", "17", "14", "16"},
                                 {"Passez Moidonc", "18", "17", "13", "10"}}
Dim tbNoteIniGr2(,) As String = {{"Lucienne Vienne", "16", "24", "19", "21"}, {"Adolf Kirpoupov", "20", "20", "23", "24"}, {"Miville St-Roche", "20", "18", "20", "12"},
                                 {"Gastonne Rochon", "19", "24", "21", "22"}, {"Luc Delaqueduc", "24", "16", "15", "24"}, {"Raphael Angelie", "21", "18", "15", "20"}}
Dim inNoteExamens, inNoteFinale, inEchec, inNoteExamens1, inNoteFinale1, inNombreEtudiant, inTotal As Integer
Dim stChaine As String
```

EDIT: HERE'S THE ENTIRE CODE

```
Public Class frmMain
    Dim tbNoteIniGr1(,) As String = {{"Jean Narrace", "16", "8", "13", "10"}, {"Chu Paspire", "20", "20", "23", "24"}, {"Yésuis Parfait", "25", "25", "25", "25"},
                                     {"Moyende Moyenner", "20", "18", "20", "12"}, {"Ia Rienla", "19", "24", "21", "22"}, {"Chue Troisième", "21", "22", "24", "24"},
                                     {"Pépé Lacasse", "21", "21", "21", "11"}, {"Jvatu Couler", "19", "18", "14", "10"}, {"Ungars Sessaye", "0", "0", "0", "25"},
                                     {"Mpassetu Tonlab", "10", "10", "25", "10"}, {"Cava Mieux", "10", "15", "20", "25"}, {"Quéyé Suisbonnw", "24", "24", "24", "24"},
                                     {"Sexy Body", "24", "6", "15", "24"}, {"Yvon Meravoir", "12", "11", "18", "15"}, {"Jeannez Assez", "25", "15", "5", "0"},
                                     {"Téreize Constance", "13", "13", "13", "13"}, {"Déhaut Etdébas", "20", "5", "25", "9"}, {"Jpasse Saligne", "13", "17", "14", "16"},
                                     {"Passez Moidonc", "18", "17", "13", "10"}}
    Dim tbNoteIniGr2(,) As String = {{"Lucienne Vienne", "16", "24", "19", "21"}, {"Adolf Kirpoupov", "20", "20", "23", "24"}, {"Miville St-Roche", "20", "18", "20", "12"},
                                     {"Gastonne Rochon", "19", "24", "21", "22"}, {"Luc Delaqueduc", "24", "16", "15", "24"}, {"Raphael Angelie", "21", "18", "15", "20"}}
    Dim inNoteExamens, inNoteFinale, inEchec, inNoteExamens1, inNoteFinale1, inNombreEtudiant, inTotal As Integer
    Dim stChaine As String

    Private Sub frmMain_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.Width = 380

        ReDim Preserve tbNoteIniGr1(tbNoteIniGr1.GetLength(0) - 1, tbNoteIniGr1.GetLength(1))
        For i = 0 To tbNoteIniGr1.GetLength(0)
            inNoteExamens = CInt(tbNoteIniGr1(i, 1)) + CInt(tbNoteIniGr1(i, 2)) + CInt(tbNoteIniGr1(i, 4))
            If inNoteExamens >= 45 Then
                inNoteFinale = inNoteExamens + CInt(tbNoteIniGr1(i, 3))
            Else
                inNoteFinale = inNoteExamens + CInt(CInt(tbNoteIniGr1(i, 3)) * inNoteExamens / 75)
            End If
            tbNoteIniGr1(i, 5) = inNoteFinale
        Next

        ReDim Preserve tbNoteIniGr2(tbNoteIniGr2.GetLength(0) - 1, tbNoteIniGr2.GetLength(1))
        For i = 0 To tbNoteIniGr2.GetLength(0)
            inNoteExamens1 = CInt(tbNoteIniGr2(i, 1)) + CInt(tbNoteIniGr2(i, 2)) + CInt(tbNoteIniGr2(i, 4))
            If inNoteExamens1 >= 45 Then
                inNoteFinale1 = inNoteExamens1 + CInt(tbNoteIniGr2(i, 3))
            Else
                inNoteFinale1 = inNoteExamens1 + CInt(CInt(tbNoteIniGr2(i, 3)) * inNoteExamens1 / 75)
            End If
            tbNoteIniGr2(i, 5) = inNoteFinale1
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnNoteGr1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnNoteGr1.Click
        rtbText.Location = New Point(98, 13)
        gbxStats.Location = New Point(466.13)

        inEchec = 0
        stChaine = ""
        stChaine = "Notes finales pour le groupe 01" & vbCrLf & "Cours 420-246" & vbCrLf & "Session Hiver 2011" &
            vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Nom" & Space(20) & "NoteF" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
        For i = 0 To tbNoteIniGr1.GetLength(0) - 1
            stChaine &= tbNoteIniGr1(i, 0) & Space(25 - tbNoteIniGr1(i, 0).Length) & tbNoteIniGr1(i, 5).PadLeft(3) & vbCrLf
            If tbNoteIniGr1(i, 5) < 60 Then
                inEchec += 1
            End If
        Next
        rtbText.Text = stChaine
        tbxEhcas.Text = CStr(inEchec)
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnNoteGr2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnNoteGr2.Click
        rtbText.Location = New Point(98, 13)
        gbxStats.Location = New Point(466.13)

        inEchec = 0
        stChaine = ""
        stChaine = "Notes finales pour le groupe 02" & vbCrLf & "Cours 420-246" & vbCrLf & "Session Hiver 2011" &
            vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Nom" & Space(20) & "NoteF" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
        For i = 0 To tbNoteIniGr2.GetLength(0) - 1
            stChaine &= tbNoteIniGr2(i, 0) & Space(25 - tbNoteIniGr2(i, 0).Length) & tbNoteIniGr2(i, 4).PadLeft(3) & vbCrLf
            If tbNoteIniGr2(i, 5) < 60 Then
                inEchec += 1
            End If
        Next
        rtbText.Text = stChaine
        tbxEhcas.Text = CStr(inEchec)
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnStatGr1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnStatGr1.Click
        rtbText.Location = New Point(466.13)
        gbxStats.Location = New Point(98, 13)

        inTotal = 0
        inNombreEtudiant = 0
        inEchec = 0

        For i = 0 To tbNoteIniGr1.GetLength(0) - 1
            inNombreEtudiant += 1
            inTotal += CInt(tbNoteIniGr1(i, 5))
            If tbNoteIniGr1(i, 5) < 60 Then
                inEchec += 1
            End If
        Next

        tbxGroupe.Text = "01"
        tbxMoyenne.Text = inTotal / inNombreEtudiant
        tbxNombreEchec.Text = inEchec
        tbxNombreEtudiant.Text = inNombreEtudiant
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnStatGr2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnStatGr2.Click
        rtbText.Location = New Point(466.13)
        gbxStats.Location = New Point(98, 13)

        inTotal = 0
        inNombreEtudiant = 0
        inEchec = 0

        For i = 0 To tbNoteIniGr2.GetLength(0) - 1
            inNombreEtudiant += 1
            inTotal += CInt(tbNoteIniGr2(i, 5))
            If tbNoteIniGr2(i, 5) < 60 Then
                inEchec += 1
            End If
        Next

        tbxGroupe.Text = "02"
        tbxMoyenne.Text = inTotal / inNombreEtudiant
        tbxNombreEchec.Text = inEchec
        tbxNombreEtudiant.Text = inNombreEtudiant
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Have you tried using breakpoints?

Comment: The whole point of debugging was so you can check your work. Give it a shot.

Comment: yep, I used it and it simply didn't ever stop when I added the breakpoint on the second redim array.

Comment: I don't know if it has something to do with my problem but it's my first time working with strict&explicit option on.

Comment: Its strange you dont get an error because you are exceeding your array boundaries

Comment: Add in a try and catch - see if an error is being thrown and if so what it is

Comment: Well, yes I get an error later when I use something related to the second array since it didn't redim when the program loaded (Index was outside the bounds of the array.) I'll post the entire code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From MSDN:

***Resizing with Preserve**. If you use **Preserve**, you can resize **only the last dimension** of the array. For every other dimension, you must specify the bound of the existing array.
For example, if your array has only one dimension, you can resize that dimension and still preserve all the contents of the array, because you are changing the last and only dimension. However, if your array has two or more dimensions, you can change the size of only the last dimension if you use **Preserve.***

valter

Comment: No, that's not really the problem since I am resizing the last dimension. `ReDim Preserve tbNoteIniGr2(tbNoteIniGr2.GetLength(0) - 1, tbNoteIniGr2.GetLength(1))` which is equivalent to `ReDim Preserve tbNoteIniGr2(5,5)` I can upload my visual studio project if you want

Comment: @user2973533 Change in the two for loops `tbNoteIniGr1.GetLength(0) and tbNoteIniGr2.GetLength(0)` to `tbNoteIniGr1.GetLength(0) - 1 and tbNoteIniGr2.GetLength(0) - 1`. Now it works